# What is proper Gradle syntax for List of Dependencies with exclusions?

Tags: maven, gradle, syntax, pom.xml

I'm both a Gradle newb and a Groovy newb.

Given that the example provided below is wrong ( fails on the exclude line ), what is the proper syntax for creating a List of Gradle dependencies along with one or more excludes? Error is:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method org.jboss:jboss-common-core() for arguments...
```

Context: Our old Maven project, which I am converting, has several BOM's (Bill of Materials). That's an empty POM packaged project that has only dependencies so that you can use it to depend them as a group. I am trying to do this in a manner appropriate to Gradle and thought a List or Array of dependencies would be the ticket. ...except I can't seem to write one. :-/

```
List stuff = [ "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api",
                            "log4j:log4j",
                            "javax.jms:jms",
                            "com.oracle:ojdbc7",
                            "javax.transaction:jta",
                            "jgroups:jgroups",
                            "org.jboss:jboss-common-core" { exclude "org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-spi" },
                            "org.jboss.cache:jbosscache-core",
                            "xml-apis:xml-apis"]
```

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'll wait to see if someone else wants the cheese, though. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't verify it, since I don't know the repos for some artifacts, but could you please try with the following piece of code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

ext.stuff = [ 
    "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api",
    "log4j:log4j",
    "javax.jms:jms",
    "com.oracle:ojdbc7",
    "javax.transaction:jta",
    "jgroups:jgroups",
    dependencies.create("org.jboss:jboss-common-core", 
        { exclude group: "org.jboss.logging", module:"jboss-logging-spi" }
    ),
    "org.jboss.cache:jbosscache-core",
    "xml-apis:xml-apis"
]

dependencies {
    compile stuff
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into('deps')
}
```

The following piece of code:

```
dependencies.create("org.jboss:jboss-common-core", 
    { exclude group: "org.jboss.logging", module:"jboss-logging-spi" }
),
```

can be replaced with (groovy syntax magic):

```
dependencies.create("org.jboss:jboss-common-core")  
    { exclude group: "org.jboss.logging", module:"jboss-logging-spi" }
,
```

Comment: Close. Your ')' is in the wrong place.  Please fix. Move to end of ..."org.jboss:jboss-common-core" ) {...

Comment: Actually it's in the right place - parenthesis are optional in groovy, I just added it for better readability.

Comment: It's accepting that because there is an overload function that takes a config closure but if you run it I think it will go 'crunch'.  .create I am using takes only one parameter.

Comment: @user447607, one parameter? Can you paste it below?

Comment: I mean I'm no expert but I think that is what I'm seeing.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html

Comment: dependencies.create("org.hibernate:hibernate-core") {
            exclude group: "org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction", modlue "jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec"
            },

Comment: Actually these are TWO parameters. Have a look a this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Opalo/45fde12768cafa56c12d). These are groovy syntax specific features.